# Why my variable's value change when page refresh in service.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here my Angular service.ts file code. That use to store the login status

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CurdService {
    
      private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(true);
      constructor() { }
    
      sendMessage(message: boolean) {
        this.subject.next(message);
    }
    
    getMessage() {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
    
    }
```

Using the below code I change that's value. Why this 'subject' value change when I page refresh. How I store that value permanently.

```
 login(){
    this.curdService.sendMessage(true);
  }

 logout(){
    this.curdService.sendMessage(false);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To permanently store and retrieve data even after a page refresh, use localStorage:

Any value you need to store permanently, for example, declare a variable:

```
var token = "message";
```

Set the item in the localStorage, note that you need a key (here it is id) to be able to retrieve it:

```
localStorage.setItem("id", token);
```

The below line will return the value message:

```
  const message =  localStorage.getItem("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `Angular Services` maintains your data throughout the life of your application. When you refresh the page, the previous communication between services will be refreshed/reset and will not be saved. In every page reload, angular services maintain a new fresh instance of the application.

If you want to save or preserve your data, you can use`localStorage, cookies, or sessionStorage` and other similar.

Comment: too bad they are editable by the freaking user hence useless